# What is the best way to keep a job as an student?

Tags: student, software

I am currently studying software engineering and all the jobs that I will take are paid for with a student grant (Scholarship). Both the company and university pay half of my salary, so I'm very cheap for either party.

For a few months now I have been working at a company as a Java Junior Developer and the company had a **HUGE** project.

From the first week I was told (by my project mates, not a manager) that the company only hires people as a student grant and when the contract finishes, you get out.

I left that job and start to search for another job. Currently I am working at **another** company, the project is already done, but they want to add more functionality.

My contract finishes in three months time and I want to keep working on the morning and studying in the afternoon. Some people in this new job told me that they came here also with the student grant but when it finished the company hires him.

I want to make a difference as a student but I don't know how.

Should I talk with my project manager now or should I wait some time to see what happen?

What is the best way to keep a job as an student?

Comment: Are you asking how to be permanently hired from an internship? I can't quite tell what you're actually trying to accomplish. (Close-voted as unclear for now.)

Comment: @scaaahu I edited the question just to give less information.

Comment: Unclear what the question is here. I get you got three months left on your current job but after that I really have no clue what you're trying to ask because your detail and question don't really ask for anything.

Comment: Your question is "What is the best way to keep a job as an student?" Short answer, ask for low salary at the end of your student job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the company that you're with funds student work with the grants directly and they are putting minimal funds into these projects yourself.

The key here is to network with managers that know and respect you, let them know that you enjoy working there and you want to continue doing so once the grant period is over. There may not be something they can offer you now (or budget for it) but by keeping the lines of communication open you will likely here if something does become available.